# Ping to another computer using TestConnection in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to test connection between different computers on the same domain using PowerShell.  Below is command i am using:

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName <hostname> -quiet
```

The output of few is `True` and for few it's `False`. I have checked the systems manually. All of them are in the same domain.

Is there any pre-requisite for the connection to be successful?

Comment: it's simply the WMI PingStatus method being called. if you get a false ... then either the system was too busy to respond OR ping is disabled for that system OR some other reason is preventing the target from responding.

Comment: True means the server is responding, false means it's not.

Answer (score 0):

No that I'm aware of... if you are testing a whole subnet, I've found this helpful previously

```
$subnet = "10.20.6."
1..254 | Foreach-Object {write-host "$Subnet$_..." (Test-Connection -ComputerName "$Subnet$_" -Quiet -Count 1 ) }
```